# Mounting a directory within a docker build

Tags: python, docker

I'm wondering how to use a simple script with a docker container.

The script is:

## example python script

```py
# Example python script
import argparse
import pathlib


def run(
    *,
    input: pathlib.Path | str,
    output: pathlib.Path | str,
) -> None:
    pathlib.Path(output).write_text(pathlib.Path(input).read_text().upper())


def main() -> int:
    desc = "example script"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=desc,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "-i",
        "--input",
        help=("input file"),
        required=True,
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "-o",
        "--output",
        help=("output file"),
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "-x",
        "--overwrite",
        help=("Whether to overwrite previously created file."),
        action="store_true",
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not pathlib.Path(args.input).exists():
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"input file {args.input} not found")

    if not args.output:
        raise argparse.ArgumentError(f"output not given")

    if pathlib.Path(args.output).exists() and not args.overwrite:
        raise FileExistsError(f"{args.output} already exists. ")

    run(input=args.input, output=args.output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

The script works fine on my system (without docker).

## example docker file

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.10.6-bullseye
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "example.py"]
```

This works (ish) after the following:

```
# build
docker build -t demo .

# run
docker run demo --help
```

Which outputs:

```
usage: example.py [-h] -i INPUT [-o OUTPUT] [-x]

    example.


options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                        input file
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        output file
  -x, --overwrite       Whether to overwrite previously created file.
```

But I'm not sure how to use it with the `-i` and `-o` arguments.

## what I'd like to do

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
echo "text" > input.txt

# Create output from input
docker run demo -i input.txt -o output.txt

# Create output from input and say it's ok to overwrite
docker run demo -i input.txt -o output.txt -x
```

And after this there by a output.txt file created which has TEXT in it.

## Error

I've tried to do this with the above command, and it doesn't work.

Eg:

```
echo "this" > input.txt

docker run demo -i input.txt -o output.txt -x
```

After this there is no `output.txt` file created which has `THIS` in it.

## Attempted solution (`--mount` within the shell command)

Using the following seems to work - but it feels as though It's a lot in a shell command :

```
docker run  \
    --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/check \
    --workdir=/check demo:latest \
    -i input.txt -o output.txt -x
```

Is there a way to do the `--mount` within the dockerfile itself?

Comment: That's not how it works. You mount into a container not into an image.

Comment: The command you show is more or less the minimum required (there are shorter `docker run -v` and `-w` options); Docker is intentionally designed so that it's hard for a container to access files on the host system.  If the main goal of your script is to read and write host files, you might find it easier to run outside a container, maybe in a Python virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a similar thing by running a compiler inside the docker container.

Obviously the docker image gets built whenever there is a new version of the compiler or the underlying image.

The container gets to run whenever I want to compile something. And here I have to mount source and target directories, but my docker command looks smaller than yours:

```
docker run --rm -v /sourcecode:/project:ro -v /compiled:/output:rw -v cache:/cache:rw compilerimagename
```

All the rest is defined within the image.